# principle component analysis -> inverse/inverted pattern

Tags: fortran, pca, inverse

I have implemented an opensource PCA code in my fortran code,
I just input the multidimentional data in to a 2 DIM matrix  ( PCA_MATRIX(imagepixels_amount,image_count))
and out come the first (up to) 7 transformed images of the PCA (they are written into the input matrix)

it works fine in most cases, but in some i get an inverse pattern (in the first 3 components) which I do not understand, because all input images show a similar pattern.

Am i missing a fundamental property of PCA which can cause such inverted patterns?

the library I'm using is: http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/math/statlib/multi/pca

I'm thankfull for any input, i wasnt able to find anything on pca inversion online

this is an example image:[image]

Comment: This is not really the best place to ask, you have programming people here answering questions about programming, not experts on PCA. That said I don't know where is a good place to ask.

Comment: There are specific stackexchange sites for statistics, data science and artificial inteligence. You should probably ask there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was due to an error in the algorithm when calculating the new components from the eigenvectors, they were added/multiplied in the wrong order